# Size of the page table

Tags: operating-systems

### Question

Consider a system which has logical address is 7 bits, physical address is 6 bits , page size is 8 words, calculate the number of pages and no.of frames, size of page table.

### Answer

### Addressing Scheme in a Paging System

Given the following information:

- Logical Address: 7 bits
- Physical Address: 6 bits
- Page Size: 8 words

We can calculate the following:

#### Page Size

The page size is 8 words, which requires $\log_2(8) = 3$ bits to address.

#### Number of Pages

With a 7-bit logical address, we can address $2^7 = 128$ different addresses. Since each page contains 8 words, we need 3 bits to address words within a page. Therefore, the number of pages is $2^{(7 - 3)} = 2^4 = 16$.

#### Number of Frames

The physical address is 6 bits. With 3 bits used to address words within a page, the remaining bits in the physical address are used to address frames. Hence, the number of frames is $2^{(6 - 3)} = 2^3 = 8$.

#### Size of Page Table

The size of the page table depends on the number of entries, each mapping a logical page number to a physical frame number. In this case, there are 16 pages and 8 frames.

Each page table entry requires:

- Logical Page Number: 4 bits (16 pages require 4 bits to represent).
- Physical Frame Number: 3 bits (8 frames require 3 bits to represent).

Therefore, each page table entry requires $4$ bits + $3$ bits = $7$ bits.

The size of the page table is calculated as follows:

$$
\text{Size of Page Table} = \text{Number of Pages} \times \text{Size of Page Table Entry} = 16 \text{ pages} \times 7 \text{ bits/page} = 112 \text{ bits}
$$

So, the size of the page table is 112 bits.

Is the page table size calculation correct or not ?